# Cannot iterate through an html collection using GetElementsByClass

Tags: javascript

```
function startup() {

   var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer")
   console.log(fontButtons)
   console.log(fontButtons.length)

   for(i=0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) {
      console.log()
   }

}
```

when i run this console.log(fontButtons) gives me an htmlCollection
but the length is 0, how is this possible?

I can't iterate over something that has a length of 0, but it still gives me the collection of the first console.log of this

Comment: Well why do you think an empty collection is not possible?

Comment: because im reading the collection of 4 items in my console

Comment: html and initializing the htmlCollection code would be great to analyze why the collection is empty.

Comment: Please describe your issue in detail. I cannot see a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsuv4dm4/ (other than missing `;`s)